# Movie making using Google earth COM API

Tags: google-earth

I am trying to programatically generate movie/video file using Google Earth COM APIs (along with Google earth Pro). But unfortunately I could not find any COM APIs to automate movie maker feature in Google earth pro.

Basically my project idea is that: client will provide tour information to server, then some server side service will launch google earth pro locally on server to export tour video to local file, which then will streamed down to client. So client will not need to have google earth plugin installed.

and also as per my knowledge generating movie file using Google earth plugin is not possible (please correct me if I am wrong)

Can anyone point me to some solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Earth COM API is being depreciated and developers are being encouraged to use the [Google Earth Plugin Api](http://code.google.com/apis/earth/) instead.

Using the plug-in in an embedded application would easily allow you to achieve this as you could just capture the frames from the plug-in and then render them to a video file using your desired codec.

I have put together [a library of controls](http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/) that work with the Google Earth Api in managed code. They may not be exactly what you need but they should give some idea of the main principals (e.g. loading, geocoding, screen-grab, etc)